# Karate returns HTTP 415 for soap request

Tags: testing, karate

I'm trying to hit a SOAP service using karate and it always returns 415, whereas the same service is successful in SOAP UI.
Response in Karate:

```
20:05:37 20:05:37.236 [ForkJoinPool-1-worker-1] DEBUG com.intuit.karate - response time in milliseconds: 37.15
20:05:37 1 < 415
20:05:37 1 < Content-Length: 0
```

```
 Given url soapServiceURL
   And header Content-Type = 'application/xml'
    And request requestPayLoad
    When method post
    Then status 200
```

Kindly advise if I'm missing something here

Answer (score 0):

Please read the docs and use `soap action` if needed: https://github.com/intuit/karate#soap-action

Karate can make any HTTP request, but you need to figure out the right headers etc. One hint is export to cURL and then you will be able to do it easily.